# GLUT Problem: error redeclaration of c++ built-in type 'wchar_t'

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Just installed GLUT and giving me `'error redeclaration of c++ built-in type 'wchar_t'`. I searched for solution and found that i should include `<graphics.h>`. But doing this didn't help. Any help?

The code is the default of any new glut project.

The code is:

```
/*
 * GLUT Shapes Demo
 *
 * Written by Nigel Stewart November 2003
 *
 * This program is test harness for the sphere, cone
 * and torus shapes in GLUT.
 *
 * Spinning wireframe and smooth shaded shapes are
 * displayed until the ESC or q key is pressed.  The
 * number of geometry stacks and slices can be adjusted
 * using the + and - keys.
 */

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>

static int slices = 16;
static int stacks = 16;

/* GLUT callback Handlers */

static void resize(int width, int height)
{
    const float ar = (float) width / (float) height;

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity() ;
}

static void display(void)
{
    const double t = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000.0;
    const double a = t*90.0;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3d(1,0,0);

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(-2.4,1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutSolidSphere(1,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(0,1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutSolidCone(1,1,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(2.4,1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutSolidTorus(0.2,0.8,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(-2.4,-1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutWireSphere(1,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(0,-1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutWireCone(1,1,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(2.4,-1.2,-6);
        glRotated(60,1,0,0);
        glRotated(a,0,0,1);
        glutWireTorus(0.2,0.8,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}


static void key(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case 27 :
        case 'q':
            exit(0);
            break;

        case '+':
            slices++;
            stacks++;
            break;

        case '-':
            if (slices>3 && stacks>3)
            {
                slices--;
                stacks--;
            }
            break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

static void idle(void)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

const GLfloat light_ambient[]  = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_diffuse[]  = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_position[] = { 2.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f };

const GLfloat mat_ambient[]    = { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat mat_diffuse[]    = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat mat_specular[]   = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat high_shininess[] = { 100.0f };

/* Program entry point */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("GLUT Shapes");

    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(key);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT,  light_ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE,  light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT,   mat_ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE,   mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR,  mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, high_shininess);

    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please post your [mcve] and complete error message.

Comment: Which GLUT implementation are you using?  How did you install it, from source or binaries?  OS?  Compiler?

Comment: I installed it from binaries.
I put 'glut32.dll' in 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64' path,
'glut32.lib' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib'
'glut.h' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\GL'.
As i saw in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ufpg11EqWzs.

Comment: Don't go anywhere near the ancient [Nate Robins GLUT](https://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html).  Use [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/), it's actually maintained.

Comment: I'm not sure about what FreeGLUT is tbh. Is there any difference between FreeGlut and Nate Robins GLUT? because my assignment is to use only GLUT.

Comment: GLUT is no longer maintained and it's license did not permit the redistribution of modified versions of the library (so no one else can update it)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit  FreeGLUT is maintained and updated  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeGLUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, codeblocks was setting the path to the compiler to the installation under old folder C:\MinGW. When I changed to the installation in the directory of codeblocks, compilation worked:

In the codeblocks, go to settings-compiler-toolchain executables, and change the compiler's installation directory to the installation of MinGW in the codeblocks directory.
Thanks to @Joao Pedro.